# Multidimenssion array compare two arrays and update first array value

Tags: php

I want to filter a array by a number and update its status in the first array.

I have two array $arr1,$arr2

```
$arr1 = array(
    0=>array('number'=>100,name=>'john'),
    1=>array('number'=>200,name=>'johnny')
);
$arr2= array(
    0=>array('number'=>300,name=>'r'),
    1=>array('number'=>100,name=>'b'),
    2=>array('number'=>200,name=>'c')
);
```

Final output should be an array like this

```
$arr1 = array(
    0=>array('number'=>100,name=>'b'),
    1=>array('number'=>200,name=>'c')
);
```

Any ideas to start off please ?

Comment: How are you retrieving this data? Because it would be a heck of a lot simpler if you have meaningful keys instead of having to inspect the `number` part...

Comment: Based on the number from second array update the name part of first array.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking whether we can simplify this problem at the source rather then do some redundant loops later.

Comment: array_intersect read about it

Comment: @RobertPodwika `array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)` wouldn't work here, it does a naive string comparison. It would either include all elements from both arrays, or none. [array-uinstersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) with a custom comparison would get closer, but it wouldn't transform the first array. OP doesn't specify what he wants to do with elements in the $arr1 but not in $arr2, but the implication is that they would remain in $arr1, where as intersection would remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For specialized array modifications like this, the method of choice is [array walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). It allows you to apply a custom function to each element in a given array.

Now, because of your data format, you will have to do a loop. Wrikken is asking if you can retrieve or transform the data to provide faster access. The algorithm below is `O(n^2)`: it will require as many cycles as there are elements in the first array times the number of elements in the second array, or exactly `count($arr1) * count($arr2)`.

```
function updateNameFromArray($element, $key, $arr2) {
    foreach($arr2 as $value) {
        if($value['number'] == $element['number']) {
            $element['name'] == $value['name'];
            break;
        }
    }
}

array_walk($arr1, "updateNameFromArray", $arr2);
```

Now, what Wrikken is suggesting is that if your arrays can be changed to be *keyed* on the `'number'` property instead, then the search/replace operation is much easier. So if this were your data instead:

```
$arr1 = array(
    100=>array('number'=>100,name=>'john'),
    200=>array('number'=>200,name=>'johnny')
);
// notice the keys are 100 and 200 instead of 0,1

$arr2= array(
    300=>array('number'=>300,name=>'r'),
    100=>array('number'=>100,name=>'b'),
    200=>array('number'=>200,name=>'c')
);
// notice the keys are 300, 100 and 200 instead of 0,1, 2
```

Then you could do this in `O(n)` time, with only looping over the first array.

```
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($arr2[$key])) {
        $value['number'] = $arr2[$key]['number'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It's not that clean but i think it would work.

```
<?php

 $arr1 = array(0=>array('number'=>100,'name'=>'john'),1=>array('number'=>200,'name'=>'johnny'));
 $arr2= array(0=>array('number'=>300,'name'=>'r'),1=>array('number'=>100,'name'=>'b'),2=>array('number'=>200,'name'=>'c'));
 foreach( $arr1 as $key=>$data1 )
  {
foreach( $arr2 as $key2=>$data2 )
{
    if( $data1['number'] == $data2['number'] )
    {
        $arr1[$key]['name'] = $arr2[$key2]['name'];
    }
 }

  }
 print_r( $arr1 );
?>
```

the output would be :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [number] => 100
        [name] => b
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [number] => 200
        [name] => c
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a simple way for this to be accomplished with generic PHP functions, so, You might need to create mapping arrays.

The way I would approach this, is creating a loop that goes through the first array, and maps the number value as a key to the index of it's place in $arr1 giving you:

```
$tmp1 = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $number_name) {
  $tmp1[$number_name['number']] = $key;
}
```

This should give you an array that looks like

```
$tmp1 [
  100 => 0,
  200 => 1
];
```

Then I would loop through the second array, get the number value, if that existed as a key in $tmp1, get the associated value (being the key for $arr1), and use that to update the name in $arr1.

```
// Loop through $arr2
foreach ($arr2 as $number_name) {
  // Get the number value
  $number = $number_name['number'];

  // Find the $arr1 index 
  if (isset($tmp1[$number])) {
    $arr1_key = $tmp1[$number];
    // Set the $arr1 name value
    $arr1[$arr1_key]['name'] = $number_name['name'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

//Set the arrays

$arr1 = array(
    array('number'=>100,'name'=>'john'),
    array('number'=>200,'name'=>'johnny')
);

$arr2= array(
    array('number'=>300,'name'=>'r'),
    array('number'=>100,'name'=>'b'),
    array('number'=>200,'name'=>'c')
);

// use a nested for loop to iterate and compare both arrays

for ($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++):

    for ($j=0;$j<count($arr2);$j++):

        if ($arr2[$j]['number']==$arr1[$i]['number'])
            $arr1[$i]['name']=$arr2[$j]['name'];

    endfor;

endfor;

print_r($arr1);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Array (
 [0] => Array ( [number] => 100 [name] => b )
 [1] => Array ( [number] => 200 [name] => c )
 )
```

That being said, you should probably reconsider the very way your data is structured. Do you really need a multi-dimensional array or can you use a simple associative array, like so:

```
 // set the arrays

 $arr1 = array(
        'john'=>100,
        'johnny'=>200          
    );

 $arr2 = array(
       'r'=>300,
       'b'=>100,
       'c'=>200
     );

// find values in arr2 common to both arrays

$arr3 = array_intersect($arr2, $arr1);

// change the key of arr1 to match the corresponding key in arr2

  foreach ($arr3 as $key=>$value) {

      $old_key = array_search($value, $arr1);
      $arr1[$key]=$arr1[$old_key];
      unset($arr1[$old_key]);

  }


print_r($arr1);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( 
   [b] => 100 
   [c] => 200 
)
```